# Enter key on ASP Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

On an aspx page I have a asp:login control inside a form. When I press the login button everything works well, but when I press the Enter key, the page is reloaded but nothing else happens. The loginbutton handler function is not accessed.

On aspx:

```
<form id="form1" class="login-form" runat="server" DefaultButton="lgLogin$LoginButton">    
    <asp:Login ID="lgLogin" runat="server" Width="100%"
        FailureText="Some text here"
        PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Some text here"          
        UserNameRequiredErrorMessage="Some text here"
        TextLayout="TextOnLeft" 
        OnAuthenticate="lgLogin_Authenticate" 
        DestinationPageUrl="~/Welcome.aspx"
        OnLoginError="lgLogin_Error"
        DisplayRememberMe="False" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Login</label>
                <div class="input-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-user"></i>                
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="UserName" CssClass="form-control placeholder-no-fix" placeholder="Login" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label visible-ie8 visible-ie9">Password</label>
                <div class="input-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="password" ID="Password" CssClass="form-control placeholder-no-fix" placeholder="Password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="AlertError" runat="server" class="alert alert-danger" visible="false">
                <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
                <span>
                    <asp:Label ID="FailureText" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions">
                <asp:Button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right" ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text='Login now' />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>           
        <TextBoxStyle CssClass="form-control placeholder-no-fix"/>
        <LoginButtonStyle CssClass="btn blue pull-right" />
    </asp:Login>
</form>
```

The lgLogin_authenticate void is only accessed when the LoginButton is pressed.

**EDIT**

It's solved. Actually, it was working well. The problem was on a .js file that it was loaded within this page. It was capturing the Enter key to do some checks, but in the end it wasn't calling the submit button.

Comment: Damn! It took me too long to realise this was my problem too! It does work now!

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       button1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Obviously, when I type the username or the password, the button is unfocused.

Comment: your AutoPostBack property of the TextBox is set to true ? should just work, it's kinda default after that!

Comment: <asp:Button type="submit" class="btn blue pull-right" ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text='Login now'  />  AutoPostBack="True" is missing in your button

Comment: It is an asp:Button, as far as I know it has no AutoPostBack property.

Comment: pls check   http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_textbox_autopostback.asp

Comment: also stackuser83 has added MSDN link

Comment: No worries, it is solved. Anyway, as I said before, I tested with AutoPostBack on every textbox. But on your previous comment you said AutoPostBack was missing in the button, but the button has no AutoPostBack property.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the AutoPostback attribute of the asp textbox to true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.autopostback.aspx

Comment: I've set AutoPostBack to true for both username and password textboxes but it doesn't login. And when I move from username's textbox to password's textbox, the page is reloaded due to the AutoPostBack.